# Watir: selector for an a-href inside the first table cell

Tags: css, ruby, cucumber, watir, gherkin

**I have** my css alias like:

```
module MyPage

  def locator(key, *options)
    hash = {
        "FIRST_TABLE_CELL_HREF" => [ :css => '#my-table td:nth-child(1):first a']
    }
  end
```

**I want** to click on that alias:

```
@page.find("FIRST_TABLE_CELL_HREF").when_present.right_click
```

**Problem:** that's a Javascript style alias, so it doesn't work.

**Question:** *how to write the same Ruby style css alias?*

**P.S.** `$('#my-table td:nth-child(1):first a')` works well in browser console.

**For @TitusFortner** that's true when you want to select specific element. But I'm using some business level language (Gherkin in my case) and I want to write an universal instruction. It'd look like `When I right click on the element "FIRST_TABLE_CELL_HREF"`. That instruction would be mapped to:

```
When(/^I right click(?: on|)(?: the|) "([^\"]*)"$/i) do |scope|
  @page.find(scope).when_present.right_click
end
```

Where `@page = @browser.visit(SomePage)`, where in turn `@browser = BrowserBase.new start_browser(ENV['BROWSER'])`

Comment: If the link is in the first table cell, does that mean it is the first link in the table? Depending on how you have defined the `find` method, you could do `:css => '#my-table a'`. It would help to clarify the question by giving the definition of the `find` method and an example of the HTML table.

Comment: @JustinKo do you mean `"FIRST_TABLE_CELL_HREF" => [ :css => '#my-table a', :index => 0]`? That doesn't work for me

Comment: I had thought without the `:index => 0` since Watir implicitly does that. However, given that did not work, I think you have to share what the `find` method does and give an example table that shows the problem. Unfortunately just knowing that it does not work does not help us determine the problem/solution.

Comment: @JustinKo look at the last section of my question please. Is that sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Watir you often don't even need to use css

`browser = Watir::Browser.new`

First link in the table:

`browser.table(id: 'my-table').link`

Link in first data cell in table:

`browser.table(id: 'my-table').td.link`

If it has to be just css for some reason:

`browser.link(css: '#my-table a')`

Also if your table is within the context of an iframe, you have to explicitly declare it, because the driver can only see the top level browsing context unless specifically switched to. With Watir this would work:

`browser.iframe(id: 'iframe_id').table(id: 'my-table').link`

This would not work:

`browser.link(css: '#iframe_id #my-table a')`

Comment: Does this not find the element you want?

`@browser.element(css: '#my-table td a')`

If it does not, can you verify that it is not inside an iframe?

Of secondary concern is that css by itself probably won't always do what you need, and this isn't affected at all by using cucumber.

Your current find method is something like this?
  `@browser.element(css: locator[scope])`

If your locator method returns a hash like this:
`{'FIRST_TABLE_CELL_HREF' => "table(id: 'my-table').td"}`
Then your find method can be like this:
  `@browser.send(locator(scope))`